# Class javax.tranxaction.xa.XAResource present in two jars

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, classloader

I try to run a JBoss7x with a quite special XA configuration to enable FCF. I configured my datasource and stuff and want to start the application now. Unfortunately I get the following Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/transaction/xa/XAResource"
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2641) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
```

JBoss has two different locations to load this special class or interface. the JEE6 jar and the jdk7 himself. Firstly WHY? And secondly, how to solve this Problem?

Here's the configuration of the datasource, but the problem is not related to the datasource. The main issue that this class present in two official oracle

```
<xa-datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/RedSheepOraDS" pool-name="RedSheepOraDSRem" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                <xa-datasource-property name="URL">
                    jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=ON) (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=node1)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=node2)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=REDSHEEP_RAC.WORLD)))
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="ONSConfiguration">
                    nodes=node1:6200,node2:6200
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="MinPoolSize">
                    200
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="MaxPoolSize">
                    200
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="InactiveConnectionTimeout">
                    5
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="TimeToLiveConnectionTimeout">
                    5
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="AbandonedConnectionTimeout">
                    5
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="ConnectionWaitTimeout">
                    5
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="PropertyCycle">
                    900
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="ValidateConnectionOnBorrow">
                    true
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="ConnectionPoolName">
                    xaPool
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="FastConnectionFailoverEnabled">
                    true
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="ConnectionFactoryClassName">
                    oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-class>oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolXADataSourceImpl</xa-datasource-class>
                <driver>ojdbc6.jar</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>****</user-name>
                    <password>****</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.vendor.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1 from dual</check-valid-connection-sql>
                    <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.vendor.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
                <timeout>
                    <blocking-timeout-millis>3000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                    <idle-timeout-minutes>1</idle-timeout-minutes>
                </timeout>
            </xa-datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="ojdbc6.jar" module="com.oracle.db">
                    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolXADataSourceImpl</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
```

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Perhaps you should add your "quite special XA configuration", since that appears to cause your issue.

Comment: Why?  It's DLL hell.  You aren't the first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978514/issue-with-xaresource-class-load-in-jboss-as-7-1

Answer (score 0):

JBoss 7x does not appear to support the UCP connector as a managed connection pool.  If you want to use UCP, you will have to manage the pool and jndi yourself.

Otherwise, use the oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource as your driver class.

Comment: Yes I know, I just wanted to test if it's not supported or not working.

Comment: @boskop UCP is an oracle thing, so it can't be managed by JBoss as provider agnostic.  If you want to use it, you have to manage it yourself.